# Yet another images in tables question alignment. Want text to start at top of cell. Not centered

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, includegraphics

I want to have a table with image in one cell and text in other cells.

I know about the issue of alignment at center of cells. So I use the trick of

```
     \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[...]`
```

But this does not do what I want. The text in the other cells in the table all start from the middle of the cell, leaving lots of empty space above.

I want the text to start from the top of the other cells.  But do not know how to do it. i.e. I want text and images to all start from top of cell.

A picture is worth a 1,000 words, so here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5in}|p{3in}|p{1.5in}|}\hline 
{AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA}&
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB\\\hline 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBB\\\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If I do not use `\raisebox` then it looks like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5in}|p{3in}|p{1.5in}|}\hline 
{AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA}&
\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB\\\hline 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBB\\\hline 
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is worst.

Any advice on how to do this?

---

**Update**

I tried the suggestion in comment to use `\vspace{0pt}` before `\includegraphics` which works, but only for `tabular`. I need it to work also for `longtable`. I did not think it will make a difference, so my MWE only used `tabular`.

Here is MWE for `longtable`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}    
\begin{document}        
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5in}|p{3in}|p{1.5in}|}\hline 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB\\\hline 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBB\\\hline 
\end{longtable}
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it works OK for tabular.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5in}|p{3in}|p{1.5in}|}\hline 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB\\\hline 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBB\\\hline 
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I need a solution that works for **longtable** and not just tabular as I use `longtable` much more.

TL 2019

Comment: Use \height in the raisebox argument , or add \vspace{0pt} before the graphic (and no raisebox)

Comment: if you don't raise it aligns at the bottom, if you lower by half the height it aligns in the centre, so if you lower by the full height it aligns...

Comment: With longtable you need `\vspace{0pt}\par` as longtable quits vmode internally at the begin of the cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `valign=t` option (from the `adjustbox` package) you can achieve the desired layout also in a `longtable` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  
\begin{document}        
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5in}|p{3in}|p{1.5in}|}\hline 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3in,valign=t]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB\\\hline 
AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA&
\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3in,valign=t]{example-image-a}&
BBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBB\\\hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

as supplement to @leandris answer, with some off-topic suggestions (which can be helpful):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{etoolbox}           % for Gin's key patches

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname Gin@ii\endcsname   % needed etoolbox
    {\setkeys {Gin}{#1}}
    {\setkeys {Gin}
      {width=\dimexpr\linewidth-\tabcolsep,  % standard graphicx settings
       valign=t, margin=0pt 6pt 0pt 6pt}     % settings from adjustbox
    }{}{}
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.5in}|p{3in}|p{1.5in}|}
    \hline
AAAA AAA AA AAA AA AAAAA AA
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        &   BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB            \\
    \hline
AAAA AAA AA AAA AA AAAAA AA
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-b}
        &   BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB            \\
    \hline
AAAA AAA AA AAA AA AAAAA AA
    &   \includegraphics{example-image-c}
        &   BBBBBBBBBBB BBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB            \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

note: your table is wider than text width!